# XSLT suppress all nodes except one

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Say I've an xml document. I want to suppress output of all nodes except one (here in example the node with nodename `name`).

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="group">
    <h3>Group</h3>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <!-- No output for all -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <div class="block">
    Name: <xsl:value-of select="concat(@first, ' ', @middle, ' ', @last)" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is my sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="visualization.xsl"?>
<group>
<student>
    <name first="Some" last="One" middle="_"></name>
    <dob>
        <date>30</date>
        <month>Feb</month>
        <year>1987</year>
    </dob>
    <nationality>NoMansLand'ian</nationality>
    <gender>male</gender>
</student>
</group>
```

But this way it prints the values inside the nodes. So I get output of `30 Feb 1987 NoMansLand'ian male`.

Why The empty template for `mach = '*'` doesn't suppress any output at all ?
Do I need to Eat the output in some expression inside that blank template ?

What is the generic way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like deanosaur said, it's because of the default processing of the text() nodes (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Try replacing your `match="*"` with `match="text()"`...

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:template match="*">` is catching the elements and which don't have specific template matches (e.g. gender, dob, nationality) and is applying default processing to their `text` child nodes.

Add one template to catch and filter these elements which doesn't processing their text children:

```
 <xsl:template match="dob | nationality | gender"/>
```

Another way, given the structure of the xml would be to ensure that `student` children are processed and filter, but only process the nodes we want:

```
 <xsl:template match="student/*"/>    <!-- do nothing  -->

 <xsl:template match="student/name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>            <!-- do something  -->
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: But if there are a long list of possible tags this list will grow too big. and its not a generic solution

Comment: You can use `<xsl:template match="*"/>` to filter as the default behavior, and selectively build match templates for the elements which you do want to process. I've update my answer to show how that might work for in this xml